# Savon: user not authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap-client, savon

I am using savon gem for accessing abc financial web services. I am getting error message user not authorize. I am using this code for accessing  response

```
@wsdl="https://webservice.abcfinancial.com/wsdl/Prospect.wsdl"
@basic_auth=["user","pass"]
@headers={"Authorization" => "Basic"}

@client = Savon.client do |globals|
  globals.wsdl @wsdl
  globals.basic_auth @basic_auth
  globals.headers @headers
end

@message = {
  :clubNumber=> 'Club 0233', 
  :firstName=> 'abc', 
  :lastName=> 'def', 
  :gender=> "male"  
}
response = @client.call(:insert_prospect, message: @message)
```

and I am getting an error message `user not authorize`. I searched it but didn't find any solution. Please help me.

Comment: are you sure the service uses basic authentication? if so can you bring up the service in a browser and verify the basic auth credentials actually work?

Comment: How would i test, if it is uses basic authentication or not?

Answer (score 0):

They are using JAX-WS.
According to this article http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/ (and google) we should use login-password in http headers.
I don't have an account on the http://abcfinancial.com so I can't test the code.
Try it:

```
require 'savon'

user = 'myLogin'
password = 'myPassword'

client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'https://webservice.abcfinancial.com/wsdl/Prospect.wsdl',
    headers: {username: user,
              password: password},
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    log: true
)

message = {
    :arg0 => {
        clubNumber: 'Club 0233',
        :personal => {
            :firstName => 'myName',
            :lastName => 'myLastName',
            :gender => 'male'
        }
    }
}

response = client.call(:insert_prospect, message: message)
```

Read this good article http://predic8.com/wsdl-reading.htm and turn on debugging (pretty_print_xml: true, log: true).